# PHP Math, Loop Variables, and Display

Tags: php

I'm currently having an issue where I'm wanting to display the amount from a variable that runs through a while loop to gather information. The while loop will use multiple products, but I only want one end result to display. Here is what I have:

```
$amountoff = NULL;
$faceval = 20;

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($que)){
  $val = $row->amount;
  $price = $row->price;
  $quantity = $row->quantity;
  //if($faceval>0){
    if($faceval >= 0){
      if($faceval < 0){
        // Do Nothing
      } else {
        if($quantity > 1){
          if($quantity * $price < $faceval){
            $amountoff = $price * $quantity;
            $faceval = $faceval - $val;
          }
        } else {
          $amountoff = $price;
          $faceval = $faceval - $val;
        }
      }
    }
  //}

}
echo money_format('%(#10n', $amountoff);
```

**My Question:** My question is why does my amount keep coming back blank or 0.00? With what I'm testing my $val = 15.00, $price = 7.50, and $quantity = 1. I can't figure out how the math is breaking or coming back as 0.00/blank. Any thoughts or suggestions? I'm not getting any PHP errors or MySQL errors; I'm just not getting anything more than 0.00 as my returned value.

**EDIT:** I have modified the if statements by taking out the first if statement altogether and I'm still getting a response of 0.00

Comment: Quickly, I can see this error here: `if($faceval=0){` change it to `if($faceval==0){`

Comment: Is $amountoff `0` before money_format?

Comment: $amountoff is set to NULL. I have had it set as: $amountoff = ''; prior to changing it to NULL

Comment: The most honest thing I can advise you is that you need to improve your skills as a programmer, and as a person who posts questions.  You have a number of conditions and variables that are clear as mud, and nowhere in your question do you explain what you're trying to do.  Your question is basically:  "I have code and it doesn't work right, why?"  The true answer is that it's because... you aren't clear on how variables, loops and conditions work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if($faceval=0){ should be

```
if($faceval==0){
```

Its never getting into that statement

Edit:  Just to clean up your code:
Edit:  Added some debugging

```
$amountoff = NULL;
$faceval = 20;
$set = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($que) && $faceval>0){
   $val = $row->amount;
   $price = $row->price;
   $quantity = $row->quantity;
   $set = true;
   if($quantity > 1 && $quantity * $price < $faceval){
       $amountoff = $price * $quantity;
       if ($price==0) echo "PRICE IS ZERO<br>";
       if ($quantity==0) echo "QTY IS ZERO<br>";
       $faceval = $faceval - $val;
   } 
   else {
          $amountoff = $price;
          if ($price==0) echo "PRICE IS ZERO<br>";
          $faceval = $faceval - $val;
   }
}
if (!$set) echo "LOOP NEVER ENTERED<br>";
echo money_format('%(#10n', $amountoff);
```

Comment: Sorry I meant for that to be >

Comment: I will clean it up and see how it goes. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I'm still getting a 0.00 as an output.

Comment: just made an edit, should help you figure out why its getting 0.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out and go from there.

Comment: Thanks again Dave, after a good night of rest if I was able to figure out that the programmer before I got here made a series of typos in the SQL statement which lead to me getting the result of zero. I really appreciate your help and advice on troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are nested, which is the wrong way to do this. You second nested if will never get hit:

```
if($faceval==0){
   if($faceval >= 0){
     if($faceval < 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your first if wrong `if($facevalue = 0) { //do something }`.

It will never go inside the if because your facevalue on top is defined as 20, check your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
  if($faceval=0){
    if($faceval >= 0){
      if($faceval < 0){
        // Do Nothing
      } else {
        if($quantity > 1){
          if($quantity * $price < $faceval){
            $amountoff = $price * $quantity;
            $faceval = $faceval - $val;
```

Your nested if statements are wrong.

You'll pass the first if `$faceval` == 0; you'll fail the second only if `$faceval < 0`, so the code you're trying to run will never be reached.

EDIT

And has also been pointed out - the initial `if ($faceval = 0)` needs to be `==`, else you'll be resetting the value, rather than checking it.